# Build-in Grails tags do not work

Tags: grails, taglib

During grails application upgrade from 1.3.8 to 2.3.9 I run into the problem that grails build-in tags are ignored.

For example lets say that GSP page has two tags:

```
<g:if test="${true}">OK</g:if>
<g:hiddenField name="test" />
```

then the result of execution will be:

```
OK
<g:hiddenField name="test" />
```

but expected result is :

```
OK
<input type="hidden" name="test" />
```

Basically tags from grails-web-2.3.9.jar are working fine but from grails-plugin-gsp-2.3.9.jar are completely ignored.

Any clue why this happens is appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I found that while executing TagLibraryLookup.afterPropertiesSet() method grailsApplication object is null, so the tag lib is not registered. Now it is not clear why it is null...

**Solotion:**
The problem was that within static constraints = { } of domain object it was a call of
ApplicationHolder?.getApplication().getMainContext()?.getBean(serviceName) method. It prevented the application from initialization of all required spring/grails beans by changing initialization sequence/flow.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some double-quotes here:

```
<g:if test=${true}>OK</g:if>
<g:hiddenField name="test" />
```

If you add them:

```
<g:if test="${true}">OK</g:if>
<g:hiddenField name="test" />
```

Does that help? Also, check for any changes to the default encoding that was made in `Config.groovy` after you upgraded.

Comment: Thank you for response. But it was just an example. Many tags from real application which used to work are not recognized by Grails anymore. Regarding Config.groovy we are using external one, so it was not changed.

Comment: You need to show an example of a built in tag that doesn't work.

Comment: Just asserting that g:hiddenField and g:include don't work doesn't contribute to any progress here.  They do work in general.  If you have scenarios where they don't work there must be some other contributing factor that leads to them not working.